# meteor app: how to properly use a button to influence the route

Tags: meteor

I'm working on a survey/wizard type of meteor application.
The interface will only have two navigation buttons, who's caption/value will be determined dynamically based on whatever step a given user is currently at.
My question is: what markup syntax should I use within each of these two button's definitions in order to direct the Iron Router to change the route. Another words, where in the button definition should I put this: this.redirect('/anotherpath') ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a button in your template. If you are using a hrefs check answer from f3rland.

html:

```
<button #id="mybutton>m<Button</button>
```

you can catch the buttonpress event with javascript

js

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
  'click #myButton': function(event, template) {
    event.preventDefault();  
    Router.go('anotherpath');
  }
});
```

The router should look like:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('anotherpath', {
    path: '/',

    layoutTemplate: 'myLayout',

    controller: myController
  });
});
```

Comment: this worked great! In place of 'another path' I put a function call to determineNextStep(), which will now dynamically calculate the next step based on the values of a persistent NavigationMap model object, and will return the appropriate path string, which it will take from the "NextStep" model field

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [Iron-Router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router) `pathFor` helper in your template

```
<a href="{{pathFor 'template-name'}}">{{buttonText}}</a>
```

That will redirect the user to the corresponding page/template.

You should also take a look at [new blaze pattern to define custom block helper](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#new-pattern-for-defining-custom-block-helpers)

**Edit:**
You could also use a custom helper for dynamic route as mentioned [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/meteor-talk/F9XivhCqWvY/G-AQRbk4AfIJ)

```
UI.registerHelper("_foo", function fooHelper() {
  var templateName = figureOutNameDynamically(this.context.criticalInfo);
  return Template[templateName];
});

<template name="foo">
  {{> _foo context=.. atts=this}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this/change the route by using the action option which will automatically cal this.render().
you can do it yourself by calling the action function but I guess it is better to use onBeforeAction/after hooks